# Accessing variable of class-object instantiated in other file

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

I'm quite green on Python and have been looking around for an answer to my particular question. Though I'm not sure if it's a Python specific question, or if I'm simply getting my OOP / design patterns confused.

I've got three files: `main.py`, `board.py` and `player.py`. Board and player each only hold a class Player and Board, main simply starts the game.

However I'm struggling with validating player positions when they are added to the board. What I want is to instantiate the board and consecutively new player object(s) in `main.py`, but check the board size in `player.py` when a new player is added to the board, to ensure the player is not outside of bounds upon creation.

As it is now I'm getting a TypeError (`getX() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'`) when attempting to access the board's size inside of `player.py`.

Most likely because the board isn't instantiated in that scope. But if I instantiate it in the scope that will be counted as a new object, won't it? And if I pass the board to the player as a variable that would surely be counted as bad practice, wouldn't it?

So how do I go about accessing the instance variables of one class from another class?

Comment: I'm not sure why passing the board instance would be bad practice. Maybe if you showed the code, I'd agree with you, but currently I don't.

Comment: Sorry. Would have addez code if it was available (i'm currently in transit). I simply thought it could potentially be a bit too much to add 1/2 more instance variables to each object

Comment: You instantiate the board once, and then pass it anywhere that needs it. These functions then have a reference to the board, but there's still only one board and it's only been instantiated once.

Comment: So maybe I've got my head in the wrong place, then? Say I instantiate the board in main and pass it as a reference `player1 = Player(x,y, board)`, wouldn't that take up more memory? Would that really be considered good practice?

Comment: Why would it take up more memory? And yes, that is exactly what you'd do. Look at some other programs and see how they do it.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea if this will help, but I made a post on how to save and load using the `Pickle` import. In the saving function, it refers back to the Player class I created. It might help you, it might not. [Here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/159818/python-how-to-save-and-load-in-python-3-6-0-using-pickle) is the link anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is asking about a concept called "dependency injection."  You should take some time to read up on it.  It details the ways of making one object available to another object that wants to interact with it.  While that's too broad to write up here, here are some of the basics:

1. You could have all objects you care about be global, or contained in a global container.  They can all see each other and interact with each other as necessary.  This isn't very object-oriented, and is not the best practice.  It's brittle (all the objects are tightly bound together, and it's hard to change or replace one), and it's not a good design for testing.  But, it is a valid option, if not a good one.
2. You could have objects that care about each other be passed to each other.  This would be the responsibility of something outside of all of the objects (in your case, basically your main function).  You can pass the objects in every method that cares (e.g. `board.verify_player_position(player1)`).  This works well, but you may find yourself passing the same parameter into almost every function.  Or you could set the parameter either through a set call (e.g. `board.set_player1(player1)`), or in the constructor (e.g. `board = Board(player1, player2)`).  Any of these are functionally pretty much the same, it's just a question of what seems to flow best for you.  You still have the objects pretty tightly bound.  That may be unavoidable.  But at least testing is easier.  You can make stub classes and pass them in to the appropriate places.  (Remember that python works well with duck typing: "If it walks like a duck and quacks like a duck, then it's a duck."  You can make testing code that has the same functions as your board and player class, and use that to test your functions.)
3. A frequent pattern is to have these objects be fairly dumb, and to have a "game_logic" or some other kind of controller.  This would be given the instances of the board and the two players, and take care of maintaining all of the rules of the game.  Then your `main` function would basically create the board and players, and simply pass them into your controller instance.  If you went in this direction, I'm not sure how much code you would need your players or board to have, so you may not like this style.

There are other patterns that will do this, as well, but these are some of the more basic.

To answer your direct questions: yes, the error you're seeing is because you're trying to invoke the class function, and you need it to be on an object.  And yes, instantiating in that case would be bad.  But **no**, passing an instance of one class to another is not a bad thing.  There's no use in having objects if they don't interact with something; most objects will need to interact with some other object at some point.

You mentioned that you have code available, but it's a good thing to think out your object interactions a little bit before getting too into the coding.  So that's the question for you:  do you want `player1.check_valid_position(board)`, or `board.check_player(player1)`, or rules.validate_move(player, some_kind_of_position_variable)`.  They're all valid, and they all have the objects inter-relate; it's just a question of which makes the most sense to you to write.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to know your exact issue without seeing some code, but I hope this is useful!

```
class Player:
    def __init__(self, x, y, player_id):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.id = player_id

class Board:
    def __init__(self, width, height):
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.players = {}

    def add_player(self, player):
        """keep track of all the players"""
        self._validate_player(player)

        # add the player to a dict so we can access them quickly
        self.players[player.id] = player

    def _validate_player(self, player):
        """whatever validation you need to do here"""
        if player.x < 0 or player.x >= self.width:
            raise ValueError("The player didn't land on the board! Please check X")

        if player.y < 0 or player.y >= self.height:
            raise ValueError("The player didn't land on the board! Please check Y")

        # whatever other checks you need to do

        # player is in a valid location!


def main():
    # we can make as few or as many players as we'd like!
    p1 = Player(10, 20, 0)
    p2 = Player(-1, 10, 1)  # invalid player

    board = Board(50, 50) # we only need to make one board

    board.add_player(p1)
    board.add_player(p2)  # value error

    running = True
    while running:  # simple game loop
        player.take_turn()  # maybe prompt user to input something
        board.update_players()  # update player positions
        board.display()
        running = board.keep_playing()  # check for win state
        # whatever code you want to run

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Here we create an instance of a Player by assigning an x and y position, and in this case also a player ID which we can use to get that player when we need them. If there's only going to be one player, we could just do something like board.player.

In my example, a ValueError is raised when an invalid Player is provided, you can of course do whatever you'd like in the event that a Player is invalid, also your game could have any number of other cases for a Player being invalid.

I've added some method calls for some methods that might make sense for a board game.

As a side note, in python, you generally don't need to write getters/setters, it's perfectly okay to access Class fields directly.

player.x = 10
if player.y == 11: etc.

and if you have need for validation of some sort that could belong in a getter/setter, you can use the @property decorator.